# How to convert and z3 expression to string using cpp?

Tags: c++, z3, smt

I am trying to create a map that corresponds to my expression variables and expression constants with an random integer value.
This is the expression: `((x || !z) && (y || !z))` where x y and z are `bool_const` expressions.

I have created a recursive function where it is able to traverse through every element in the expression. But in the mapping function I've to give an INTEGER and a STRING as inputs.

```
map<int,string> symbols; 
void walk(expr e)
{     

    if(e.is_const())
    {   
        std::cout <<"ARGUMENT: " << e<< endl;
        int ran_num = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        symbols.insert(pair<int,string>(ran_num,e.to_string)); 
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"APP: " << e.decl().name() << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < e.num_args(); i++)
        {    int ran_num = (rand() % 10) + 1;
             symbols.insert(pair<int,string>(ran_num,e.decl().name())); 
             walk(e.arg(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Here the problem is occurring with

```
symbols.insert(pair<int,string>(ran_num,e.to_string)
```

where `e.to_string` is not able to interpret as string

and

```
symbols.insert(pair<int,string>(ran_num,e.decl().name()))
```

is also not able to interpret the `e.decl().name()` part as STRING.

How do I convert them to string in order to satisfy my mapping function?

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler is telling you, `name` is not a `string`, it's a `symbol`, defined here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3_1_1symbol.html

If you want to turn it into a string, it does provide a `str` method; so you should say something like `e.decl().name().str()`.

But before getting into the details, you should really review the class hierarchy that represents Z3 Expressions first. Start here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3_1_1expr.html

Comment: No problem. The proper way to indicate an answer has helped you on stack overflow is to “accept” it using the little check mark next to it. This way the next person who has the same question can visually identify the right response.